# Text mining error in R : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, text-mining, tidyr

I've done google searches, viewed the current Errata for the book, and searched the error in stack overflow and haven't found an answer. I'm following along in the book on pages 4-10.

This part runs fine:

```
 original_books <- austen_books() %>%
 group_by(book) %>%
 mutate(linenumber = row_number(),
     chapter = cumsum(str_detect(text, regex("^chapter [\\divxlc]",
                                             ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
ungroup()
original_books

tidy_books <- original_books %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text)
tidy_books

data(stop_words)

tidy_books<- tidy_books %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)

tidy_books %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)

tidy_books %>%
  count(word, sort= TRUE) %>%
filter(n>600) %>%
mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
ggplot(aes(word, n)) +
geom_col() +
xlab(NULL) +
coord_flip()

hgwells <- gutenberg_download(c(35, 36, 5230, 159))

tidy_hgwells <- hgwells %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)

tidy_hgwells %>%
count(word, sort=TRUE) 

bronte <- gutenberg_download(c(1260, 768, 969, 9182, 767))  

tidy_bronte <- bronte %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
anti_join(stop_words)

tidy_bronte %>%
count(word, sort=TRUE)

frequency <- bind_rows(mutate(tidy_bronte, author="Bronte Sisters"),
                   mutate(tidy_hgwells, author = "H.G. Wells"),
                   mutate(tidy_books, author = "Jane Austen")) %>%
        mutate(word = str_extract(word, "[a-z']+")) %>%
        count(author, word) %>%
        group_by(author) %>%
                 mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>%
                 select(-n) %>%
                 spread(author, proportion) %>%
                 gather(author, proportion, 'Bronte Sisters':'H.G. Wells')
   frequency
```

But when I run this code:

```
ggplot(frequency, aes(x=proportion, y='Jane Austen', 
                  color=abs('Jane Austen' - proportion))) +
geom_abline(color="gray40", lty=2) +
geom_jitter(alpha=0.1, size=2.5, width=0.3, height=0.3) +
geom_text(aes(label= word), check_overlap=TRUE, vjust=1.5) +
scale_x_log10(labels= percent_format()) +
scale_y_log10(labels= percent_format()) +
scale_color_gradient(limits= c(0, 0.001), 
                   low= "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
facet_wrap(~author, ncol=2) +
theme(legend.position="none") +
labs(y="Jane Austen", x=NULL)
```

I get this error:  Error in "Jane Austen" - proportion : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

This is the structure of frequency:

```
> str(frequency)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   57818 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ word       : chr  "a" "a'most" "a'n't" "aback" ...
 $ Jane Austen: num  9.19e-06 NA 4.60e-06 NA NA ...
 $ author     : chr  "Bronte Sisters" "Bronte Sisters" "Bronte Sisters" 
               "Bronte Sisters" ...
 $ proportion : num  3.19e-05 1.59e-05 NA 3.98e-06 3.98e-06 ...
```

Proportion and Jane Austin have numeric values but there are also NAs.  I tried to remove them but it didn't help, plus I figured the book would have brought this up as a potential issue.

These are the libraries I'm using. When I run them I don't see any conflicts that might mask a function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(janeaustenr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gutenbergr)
library(scales)
```

I'm using RStudio Version 1.1.442 on Windows 10. I'm using R 3.4.4

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: `color=abs('Jane Austen' - proportion)` doesn't make any sense to me. Did you copy that correctly?

Comment: are you sure you should be using quotes rather than back-ticks \`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is easily overlooked. You need backticks `` around Jane Austen not quotes. Jane Austen is not a name in this case, but a column name in `frequency`. And column names with a space need backticks.

It should be:

```
ggplot(frequency, aes(x = proportion, y = `Jane Austen`, color = abs(`Jane Austen` - proportion))) +
.....
```

not

```
ggplot(frequency, aes(x=proportion, y='Jane Austen', color = abs('Jane Austen' - proportion))) +
.....
```